# How do I set up an icon inside Relm's view! macro?

Tags: rust, gtk, rsvg

I am using Rust stable 1.30 and Relm. I figured out how to set up the default window size, but don't know how to set up the icon, at least inside the view! macro.

This is my main.rs

```
extern crate gtk;
extern crate chessground;
#[macro_use]
extern crate relm;
extern crate relm_attributes;
#[macro_use]
extern crate relm_derive;
extern crate shakmaty;
extern crate rsvg;

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::GtkWindowExt;
use relm::Widget;
use relm_attributes::widget;

use shakmaty::{Square, Board};
use chessground::{Ground, UserMove, SetBoard};

use rsvg::{Handle};

use self::Msg::*;

#[derive(Msg)]
pub enum Msg {
    Quit,
    PieceMoved(Square, Square),
}

#[widget]
impl Widget for Win {
    fn model() -> Board {
        Board::default()
    }

    fn update(&mut self, event: Msg) {
        match event {
            Quit => gtk::main_quit(),
            PieceMoved(orig, dest) => {
                if let Some(piece) = self.model.remove_piece_at(orig)     {
                    self.model.set_piece_at(dest, piece, false);
                    self.ground.emit(SetBoard(self.model.clone()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    view! {
        gtk::Window {
            title: "Chessground",
            property_default_width: 600,
            property_default_height: 600,
            #[name="ground"]
            Ground {
                UserMove(orig, dest, _) => PieceMoved(orig, dest),
            },
            delete_event(_, _) => (Quit, Inhibit(false)),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let icon = Handle::new_from_str(include_str!("wQ.svg")).expect("Could not find icon !");
    // how to set up the given icon ?
    Win::run(()).expect("initialized gtk");
}
```

I mean, how to set up the icon defined in main to the window as its icon ?
Notice that the icon has been instantiated with rsvg crate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've managed :

- Making an handle from the svg file
- pass a reference to the result into the icon property.

Which gives me :

```
extern crate gtk;
extern crate chessground;
#[macro_use]
extern crate relm;
extern crate relm_attributes;
#[macro_use]
extern crate relm_derive;
extern crate shakmaty;
extern crate rsvg;

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::GtkWindowExt;
use relm::Widget;
use relm_attributes::widget;

use shakmaty::{Square, Board};
use chessground::{Ground, UserMove, SetBoard};

use rsvg::{Handle};
use rsvg::HandleExt;  

use self::Msg::*;

#[derive(Msg)]
pub enum Msg {
    Quit,
    PieceMoved(Square, Square),
}

#[widget]
impl Widget for Win {
    fn model() -> Board {
        Board::default()
    }

    fn update(&mut self, event: Msg) {
        match event {
            Quit => gtk::main_quit(),
            PieceMoved(orig, dest) => {
                if let Some(piece) = self.model.remove_piece_at(orig) {
                    self.model.set_piece_at(dest, piece, false);
                    self.ground.emit(SetBoard(self.model.clone()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    view! {
        gtk::Window {
            title: "Chessground",
            property_default_width: 600,
            property_default_height: 600,
            // HERE
            icon: &Handle::new_from_str(include_str!("wQ.svg"))
                .expect("Could not find icon !")
                .get_pixbuf()
                .expect("No pixbuf for the icon !"),
            #[name="ground"]
            Ground {
                UserMove(orig, dest, _) => PieceMoved(orig, dest),
            },
            delete_event(_, _) => (Quit, Inhibit(false)),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    Win::run(()).expect("initialized gtk");
}
```